# Setting property of element in Javascript not reflecting in DOM

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to set the height of an element using JS. It's part of an Ionic project, and the following is the code I'm using:

```
var screenHeight = (ionic.Platform.isIOS()) ? window.screen.height : window.innerHeight * window.devicePixelRatio;

var companyHeight = screenHeight - 140 -document.getElementById('footer').offsetHeight;

document.getElementById('companyinfo').setAttribute("style","height:" + companyHeight + "px");
```

It all runs fine, and if I type `document.getElementById('companyinfo')` into the Chrome developer console I see the element as I modified it to be. However for some reason it's not updating in the actual DOM.

Comment: Did you try `document.getElementById('companyinfo').style.height = companyHeight + "px"`?

Comment: Yep, I've tried doing that and I've also tried setting .className to a class with the correct CSS. No property I set of the element makes it to the DOM. @LostMyGlasses

Comment: be sure the script is after the element or bind it window.onload

Comment: The element definitely exists at the time of running (verified by using breakpoints), and that is literally the only time the string 'companyinfo' appears in an HTML file anywhere in my project. It's the only id.@Bob Sponge @kpsingh

Comment: @JamesThorpe I'm using Chrome's inspect element tool, which I understand updates dynamically. Further evidence would be that the element isn't adjusting to the height it's being set to either.